# nginx rewrite not redirecting to wanted URL

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to have my nginx rewrite a URL so it displays properly for older links.

I have send out links like website.de/a/b/c/d/something.html in older mails. now my boss changed the URL to be like website.de/d/something.html and moved all old files to the new directory.

That means that when I call website.de/a/b/c/d/something.html I get an "404 not found" error, when I call website.de/d/something.html I get something.html.

I tried redirecting this using different approaches.
I tried

```
rewrite ^(/a/b/c/d/something.html /d/something.html permanent;
```

I also tried

```
location /a/b/c/d {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /d redirect; 
}
```

I also tried to alter the example given by ubuntuusers.de, which is

```
rewrite  ^/artikel/(.*)$  /artikel.php?id=$1?  last;
```

into

```
rewrite  ^/a/b/c/d/(.*)$  /d/$1?  last;
```

they all don't seem to work.

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you placing the `rewrite` statement? Are you trying to redirect a single URI or all URIs that begin with `/a/b/c/d`?

Comment: i am placing this inside server {}.
I am trying to redirect all urls that begin with /a/b/c/d, but am fine with putting every single one in there since there are only about 50 of them.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/a/b/c/d/(.*)$ /d/$1 permanent;`. Test the configuration using `nginx -t` and/or `nginx -T`.

Comment: thank you, this works just fine, it didn't work at all at first but then I noticed that the configfile I was editing was beeing overwriten by my coworker... sometimes it's the simplest solutions...